# jQuery Mobile // theming my dynamic dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, themes, theming

in my notification dialog, 
i want to specified by parameter dialog box type.
but theming isnt manage after all, so input and others arent theme with css from my javascript function.

HTML :

```
   <div id="notification" data-role="page" >

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
        </div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
function notification(title, text, notification_transition){
    $.mobile.changePage( "#notification", {
            transition: notification_transition,
            role: "dialog"
    } );


    $("#notification h1").html(title);
    $("#notification p.message").html(text);

    $("#notification div[data-role=content]").html('<p class="message"></p>'+
        '<p>Identifiant</p>'+
        '<input type="text" value="" data-theme="a">');


    try
    {
      navigator.notification.vibrate(500);
    }
    catch(error) {}
}
```

how relaunch jaquery mobile theming after $("#notification div[data-role=content]").html();
thank in advance
Metos

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-refresh-the-theme-of-a-button